# Regex pattern for matching the year after some character

Tags: regex

I need to group the year after † char.

The pattern I found useful: `†\D*(?<death_year>\d+)*`

(`† 1656`), (ur. 1520, `† ok. 1585`) - it works fine

but in this case:

(`† 21` VII 1595)

I need to match only the last group of digits

I can rely on `)` but those cases are possible: († 1656 ), († 1656? ), († 1656?)

**Can you help me figure it out?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the first 4-digit chunk after than char:

```r
†.*?(?<death_year>\d{4})
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cPYRU3/1/). Here, `†` is matched first, then `.*?` consumes zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then `(?<death_year>\d{4})` captures four digits.

Although in this case it seems redundant, a check for "exactly four digits" might make it safer:

```r
†.*?\b(?<death_year>\d{4})\b
†.*?(?<!\d)(?<death_year>\d{4})(?!\d)
†(?:.*?\D)??(?<death_year>\d{4})(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cPYRU3/2). Here, `\b` fails the match if the four digits have a letter/digit/underscore on either side, `(?<!\d)`/`(?!\d)` does the same if there is a digit on either side, and the third option does the same as the second except without a lookbehind (`(?:.*?\D)??` matches an optional occurrence of any 0+ non-linebreak chars as few as possible, and then a non-digit char *lazily*, so that 4 digits could be captured right after `†`).

Comment: I think `†(?:.*?\D)??(?<death_year>\d{3,4})(?!\d)` will be perfect for me, thank you!